# Mostrar imágenes en VueJs y Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hola deseo cargar imágenes con VueJs en Laravel pero no puedo de la siguiente forma.

`Dato.image` contiene el nombre de la imagen

```
<img src="/images/{{Dato.image}}" class="img-responsive" height="70" width="90">
```

Comment: el Tag `image` está en un archivo `blade` o en un archivo  `.vue` ?

Comment: {{Dato.image}} es vue despues de hacer un v-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para poder añadir código `JavaScript` al atributo `src` deberá bindear haciendo uso de los dos puntos **:** antes del atributo y como se trata de JS podrá concatenar la palabra `images` antes.  [Documentación ;)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions)

```
<img :src="'images'+ Dato.image" class="img-responsive" 
  height="70" width="90">
```

Si no necesita añadir la palabra `images` antes de, quedaría de la siguiente forma. Pensado para un Single File Component `.vue`

```
<img :src=Dato.image class="img-responsive" 
      height="70" width="90">
```

O si se siente cómodo con los [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings), quedaría.

```
<img :src="`images/${Dato.image}`" class="img-responsive" 
          height="70" width="90">
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, con la primer opción funciono como queria..