# Django REST Framework - Vuejs concatenar img src con variable y texto

Tags: django, vue.js, djangorestframework

Estoy tratando de mostrar en una lista de elementos una imagen, usando los con componentes de vue (app.vue).
Las imágenes vienen de la api REST, y lo que llega en el campo imagefield es la ruta a la imagen guardada en la carpeta media, y necesito mostrarla en la tabla.

Cuando lo coloco de ésta manera funciona correctamente:

```
<img src="../../media/default/default_avatar.png">
```

Pero necesito ponerlo mas o menos así en mi código pero no funciona:

```
<img :src="'../..' + user.user_image">
```

Ambas guardan la misma ruta pero de igual manera sólo me funciona el primer ejemplo

Ya probé la respuesta que daban [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200198/mostrar-im%C3%A1genes-en-vuejs-y-laravel) y no me funcionaron tampoco

Alguna idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplemente tendrias que concatenar todo lo que necesites, pero las variables deben estar dentro de ${tuVariable}

```
<img :src="`../../${user.user_image}`">
```